# I'm getting strange numbers when using the VBA Height function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the Height function in VBA but I am getting strange numbers. Instead of returning the height of a range, it is returning the height of a range multiplied by 15. For example, the following simple function :

```
Function h(c1 As Range) As Double
h = c1.Height
End Function
```

would give a value of 15 if c1 was a single cell, would give 30 if c1 was two cells high, and so on. I should clarify that I am using this as part of a larger function, but it is this issue that is causing the problem. I wanted to make a function as simple as possible to see if the problem remained, and it has. I really don't understand why this is happening, I have used the height function before with no problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: It's not that strange - default row height in Excel is 15 [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)). If you just want to know how many rows you've got in a range, use `c1.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the height property is. The height is its height in points...

From here..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215509%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Returns the height of all the rows in the range specified, measured in points. Returns Null if the rows in the specified range aren't all the same height. Read/write Variant.
Remarks

You can use the Height property to return the total height of a range of cells.
Differences between RowHeight and Height include the following:
Height is read-only.
If you return the RowHeight property of several rows, you will either get the row height of each of the rows (if all the rows are the same height) or Null (if they're different heights). If you return the Height property of several rows, you will get the total height of all the rows.
Example

This example doubles the height of row one on Sheet1.
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1)
    .RowHeight = .RowHeight * 2
End With